# Mapping of composite key with both elements as foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have a simple Spring-Hibernate application.
I have 3 classes crop, market and farmer with structure something like :

```
class crop  
{  
    private int cropId;  
}  
class market  
{   
    private int marketId;  
}  
class farmer   
{  
    private Crop crop;  
    private Market market;  
}
```

farmer table has a composite key{cropid, marketid}.
Now, how do I map this relationship with composite key element `cropid` and `marketid` referencing to crop and market table respectively in the `.hbm.xml` file .
I am quite new to hibernate and spring. Any suggestions will be of great help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the farmer.hbm.xml you need to make a `composite-id` like this

```
<composite-id class="FarmerId" mapped="true">
        <key-property name="cropid"/>
        <key-property name="marketid"/>
</composite-id>
```

and write a class `FarmerID` that implements `Serializable` and overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()`

In `equals()` you test if the Objects are the same or have the same values and return a boolean. In `hashCode()` you generate a hash value and return it.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if ((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
        return false;

    FarmerID test = (FarmerID) obj;
    boolean flagCrop = cropid == test.cropid;
    boolean flagMarket = marketid == test.marketid;

    return flagCrop && flagMarket;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + cropid.hashCode();
    hash = 31 * hash + marketid.hashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the ID as a separate class, would it be a better approach? Also, can you give an example of how to override the equals() and hashcode() ?

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is a better approach. It's the only one I used so far.